# Pythonic way of using enum to select and run a particular sub method?

Tags: python, enums

I have a function that will be called by an end user, and this function accepts an int argument from 1 to 3 inclusive. Depending on the int, I want the function to run a seperate sub method. I would usually do this with if statements as below, but I am looking for a cleaner / more pythonic way to do this using `Enum`.

```
def user_function(user_arg: int) -> float:
    if user_arg == 1:
        return sub_method_1()
    elif user_arg == 2:
        return sub_method_2()
    elif user_arg == 3:
        return sub_mthod_3()
    print(f"Error: user_arg must be in [1,2,3]. Supplied argument: {user_arg}")
```

Ideally the function would look something like

```
from enum import Enum

class UserMethod(Enum):
    FIRST_METHOD = 1
    SECOND_METHOD = 2
    THIRD_METHOD = 3

   def choose_method(self):
       #... use enum to choose from the 3 sub methods ...

# This function is now much cleaner
def user_function(user_arg: int) -> float:
    um = UserMethod(user_arg)
    return um.choose_method()
```

I am confused on how to use `Enum` on how to do this, or if this is even the best way?

Comment: Using a dictionary is your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this at the moment is to use the `aenum` library<sup>1</sup>:

```
from aenum import Enum

class UserMethod(Enum):
    #
    _init_ = 'value method'
    #
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self.method(*args, **kwds)
    #
    def first(blah):
        return blah
    #
    def second(spam=2):
        return spam
    #
    def third(this, that):
        return this, that
    #
    FIRST_METHOD = 1, first
    SECOND_METHOD = 2, second
    THIRD_METHOD = 3, third
```

Each method is stored on the enum member itself, and calling the member passes the call to the appropriate function.

```
--> list(UserMethod)
[<UserMethod.FIRST_METHOD: 1>, <UserMethod.SECOND_METHOD: 2>, 
<UserMethod.THIRD_METHOD: 3>]

--> UserMethod.THIRD_METHOD("hello", "world")
('hello', 'world')
```

and

```
# This function is now much cleaner
def user_function(user_arg: int) -> float:
    return UserMethod(user_arg).method
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it even simpler (that is, without relying on Python Enums):

```py
def user_function(user_arg: int) -> float:
    assert user_arg in [1,2,3], \
        f"Error: user_arg must be in [1,2,3]. Supplied argument: {user_arg}"

    return [sum_method_1, 
            sub_method_2,
            sub_method_3][user_arg-1]()
```

Answer (score 0):

On your method `choose_method` you can get the selected `Enum` using `self` like this:

```
def choose_method(self):
    print(self)  # Will print the Enum atributte
```

With this you can create a dict pointing to another methods;

```
def choose_method(self):
    methods = {
        UserMethod.FIRST_METHOD: self.sub_method_one,
        UserMethod.SECOND_METHOD: self.sub_method_two,
        UserMethod.THIRD_METHOD: self.sub_method_three,
    }

    return methods.get(self)()

def sub_method_one(self):
    print("Method 1")

def sub_method_two(self):
    print("Method 2")

def sub_method_three(self):
    print("Method 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using enums would not be my first impulse - I would argue that it wouldn't be pythonic to use one in this scenario, and I don't think you can justify using an enum. You'll probably just want to map the user's input to a function using a dictionary:

```
def first_function():
    print("In first!")

def second_function():
    print("In second!")

def third_function():
    print("In third!")


functions = {
    1: first_function,
    2: second_function,
    3: third_function
}

functions[1]()
```

Output:

```
In first!
>>>
```

In this case, the keys are integers, but they could be strings, too - or anything. I also just hardcoded the `1` in `functions[1]()`, but you get the idea.